# Binding model to kendogrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a modal popup which is having 3 different kendo grids.right now what we are doing is read the value from controller like below

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .Model(model =>
  {
     model.Id(p => p.Id);
  })
 .Read(read => read.Action
        ("GetLines", "CO",
            new
               {
                 projectId = @parameters.projectId,
               }
        ).Data("coaHelper.GetParameters")
      )
   )
```

Right now I added three lists to my modal class. Is there any way to bind this modal properties to kendogrid?

Eg : my modal class name is COAModal.

```
    Class COAModal{
        public int ProjectID{}
        public List<A> As;
        public List<B> Bs;
        public List<C> Cs;
    }
```

I want to bind As to KendoGrid1 and Bs to KendoGrid2 and Cs to KendoGrid3

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the [Local Binding Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/local-data-binding)

You would have to:

- Pass the model to the grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.As)
```

- Remove the Read property of Datasource which is used for Remote Binding.